# Single MySQL query with count and sum

Tags: sql, mysql, count, sum

Hi there I have an SQL table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `designerswave_article_visited` (
  `article_visited_article_id` smallint(5) NOT NULL,
  `article_visited_user_id` smallint(5) NOT NULL,
  `article_user_rating` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `article_id` (`article_visited_article_id`,`article_visited_user_id`)
)
```

And a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT SUM(article_user_rating) AS total_rating, COUNT(article_visited_user_id) AS hits
FROM article_visited
WHERE article_visited_article_id =1
GROUP BY article_visited_user_id
```

My problem is the rating could be 0 or NULL if the user hasn't rated the article. However in order get the average ratings I need to sum all the ratings that aren't 0 or NULL and divide by the total number of ratings.

I could do this quite easily with two queries using a where clause. But i'm interested to know if I could do it in a single query. Such as a where "article_user_rating > 0" within the SUM(). I'm sure i've seen something similar done before, but I can't find any documentation on it.

Comment: I'm confused, you're selecting a particular `article_visited_article_id` (1), and grouping by the `article_visited_user_id`, but the combination of those two columns is a unique key on the table, so that means you'll only ever have one row come up for each user. The `GROUP BY` will never group any rows.

What exactly are you trying to select? The average rating of a particular article?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extend the where clause, but as Chad said, I'm not sure if this is really what you want:

```
SELECT SUM(article_user_rating) AS total_rating, COUNT(article_visited_user_id) AS hits
FROM article_visited
WHERE article_visited_article_id =1 and article_user_rating > 0
GROUP BY article_visited_user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can read [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html), in MySQL "*group functions ignore NULL values*". Then the null values can be ignored.

For the [SUM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) aggregate function, the `0` value just can be ignored because `X+0=X`.